# Is it possible to manipulate negative time values in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

Is there a way to generate negative time values in Python?

I want to generate a time range ranging from -4 minutes to a variable positive time (between 5 to 10 min), something like this:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
time_range = range(-datetime.time(minute=4), datetime.time(minute=5))
# or
time_range = pd.date_range(-datetime.time(minute=4), datetime.time(minute=5))
```

But datetime does not seem to support negative values.

I need it to generate a graph like the following one but with a time/datetime index instead of integer values (A time/datetime index is especially useful on a plotly graph as it gives a readable index at any zoom level)
[image: Graph with int index]

In addition, I believe that the possibility to generate negative time values could have many other applications.

Comment: [dateutil.relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) might be useful here

Comment: Sounds like you're actually asking about durations?

Answer (score 0):

datetime.time doesn't accept negative values

Maybe you can try to do something with timedelta

```
from datetime import timedelta
delta = timedelta(minutes=-4)
```

I hope this clue will help you.

Saying “thanks” is appreciated, but it doesn’t answer the question. Instead, **vote up** the answers that helped you the most! If these answers were helpful to you, please consider saying thank you in a more constructive way – by contributing your own answers to questions your peers have asked here.

Comment: Telling someone how to use the site properly in your answer is kind of rude. It assumes they don't already know.